# Deleting values based on a vector indexes

Tags: r, vector, indexing

My data set carries duplication. I am deleting a resultant vector from an original vector (using these statements).

```
  elements_LON <- longitude %in% Point_Long
  new_LOG <- longitude[! elements_LON]

  **# longitude: Its the original vector 
  **# Point_Long: Resultant vector (Subset of longitude vector)****
```

It makes two vectors un-equal for plotting as it deletes repeated values as well. I need to perform deletion based on the indices and not on the values. Can anyone please suggest a way ? Thanks

Comment: Please give a reproducable example! [mcve] What is your desired output?

Comment: you want to delete the duplicated values of Point_Long only once ?

Comment: yes, exactly. Only once.

Comment: Check out  `duplicated` function. Duplicated elements will be marked as `TRUE`. Then you can use this to delete those elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given two vectors a and b

```
(a <- seq(1:10)) #initial values
[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
b <- c(3,5,7) #values to exclude
(c <- ifelse(!(a %in% b),a,NA)) # initial vector minus the values of b (but of the same length as a)
[1]  1  2 NA  4 NA  6 NA  8  9 10
```

you can plot the same length vectors now